# Beier-Neely Warp Implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've been trying to implement the Beier-Neely morphing algorithm ([description](http://www.hammerhead.com/thad/morph.html)) in Matlab and am having trouble.

I've got it working for the most part, except, the end image is rotated 180 degrees, and for non-square images, the destination image tries to sample pixels outside the source image's bounds.

I'm not very experienced with Matlab, so it's probably some silly mistake, however, I have calculated a few pixels by hand and gotten out-of-bounds coordinates with non-rectangular images. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, because I haven't seen any reference to this sort of behaviour on any other site that talks about Beier-Neely.

```m
function morphed = bnmorph( im, inputLines, targetLines )
%BNMORPH Takes image and two sets of lines.
% Morphs image from inputLines to targetLines

[xSize,ySize,~] = size(im);
[numPoints,~] = size(targetLines);
numLineSegments = int32(numPoints/2);

% Make sure there are no horizontal or vertical lines
conditionlines(inputLines);
conditionlines(targetLines);

% Preallocate space
morphed = im;

% For each pixel in the destination image, calculate the pixel to 
% sample from the source image.
for y = 1:ySize
    for x = 1:xSize
        X = [x y];
        Xsource = zeros(1,2);
        dsum = zeros(1,2);
        weightsum = 0;
            % For each line segment
            for i = 1:numLineSegments
                % Indices for the endpoints of the segments
                i1 = (i-1)*2+1;
                i2 = i1 + 1;

                % Get Pi, Qi, the end points for the line segment i
                % in the dst image
                Pi = targetLines(i1, :);
                Qi = targetLines(i2, :);

                % Get the vector QPi
                QPi = Qi - Pi;

                % Get Pi', Qi', the end points for the line segment i
                % in the src image
                Pisource = inputLines(i1,:);
                Qisource = inputLines(i2,:);

                % Get the vector QPi'
                QPisource = Qisource - Pisource;

                % Calculate u = (X-Pi).(QPi) / ||QPi||^2
                u = dot((X - Pi), QPi) / (QPi(1).^2 + QPi(2).^2);

                % Calculate v = (X-Pi).perp(QPi) / ||QPi||
                % where perp(QPi) = [-QPi(2), QPi(1)]
                v = dot((X - Pi), perp(QPi)) / sqrt(QPi(1).^2 + QPi(2).^2);

                % Calculate Xi', the pixel to sample in src image
                % Xi' = Pi'+u*QPi' + v*perp(QPi') / ||QPi'||
                Xisource = Pisource+u*QPisource+(v*perp(QPisource) / sqrt(QPisource(1).^2 + QPisource(2).^2));


                % Add this pixel to the weight
                % Does nothing when only one line segment
                Di = Xisource - X;
                if u < 0
                    dist = sqrt((X(1)-Pi(1)).^2+(X(2)-Pi(2)).^2);
                elseif u > 1
                    dist = sqrt((X(1)-Qi(1)).^2+(X(2)-Qi(2)).^2);
                else
                    dist = abs(v);
                end
                length = sqrt(QPi(1).^2 + QPi(2).^2);
                p = 0.5; % Defines strength of lines relative to length. Range: [0,1]. If 0, all lines have same weight, if 1, longer lines carry more weight than shorter ones
                a = 0.1; % Defines strength of line based on distance from point. Lower values = more control, larger value = more smooth warping
                b = 1; % Defines strength fall-off based on distance from point. Good Range: [0.5,2]. If 0, pixel affected by all lines equally, if large, then only affected by nearest lines
                weight = (length.^p / (a + dist)).^b;
                dsum = dsum + (Di * weight);
                weightsum = weightsum + weight;
            end

            % Calculate final source pixel
            % Will equal Xisource when only one line segment       
            Xsource = X + dsum / weightsum;


            % Bounds check to set out of bounds pixels to teal
            % Shouldn't be needed as far as I'm aware
            [xSize, ySize, ~] = size(im);
            nullCol = false;
            if int32(Xsource(1)) <= 0
                Xsource(1) = 1;
                nullCol = true;
            elseif int32(Xsource(1)) > xSize
                Xsource(1) = xSize;
                nullCol = true;
            end
            if int32(Xsource(2)) <= 0
                Xsource(2) = 1;
                nullCol = true;
            elseif int32(Xsource(2)) > ySize
                Xsource(2) = ySize;
                nullCol = true;
            end

            if nullCol == true
                morphed(X(1), X(2), :) = [0, 255, 255];
            else
                % Set pixel X in dst image
                morphed(X(1), X(2), :) = im(int32(Xsource(1)), int32(Xsource(2)), :);
            end
     end
end

subplot(1, 2, 1);
imshow(im);
line([inputLines(1,1) inputLines(2,1)], [inputLines(1,2) inputLines(2,2)], 'Color',[.0 1.0 .0]);
subplot(1, 2, 2);
imshow(morphed);
line([targetLines(1,1) targetLines(2,1)], [targetLines(1,2) targetLines(2,2)], 'Color',[.0 1.0 .0]);

end
```

Here is some output from the above code. The function should morph point P' in the source image to point P in the destination image. And likewise, point Q' to point Q.

[image: Square Image, with single line. Is correct, except should be rotated 180 degrees.]

This is correct, except should be rotated 180 degrees

[image: Rectangle Image. Incorrect rotation and scaling]

This middle image (with the teal) should also be rotated 180 degrees, and stretched along the long side of the triangle, not the wide side.

I have seen mention on the matlab site that pixel coordinates are done in (y,x) instead of (x,y). Using `morphed(X(2), X(1), :) = im(int32(Xsource(2)), int32(Xsource(1)), :);` fixes the rotation issue for the square image, however, it turns the rectangular image into a larger square (i.e if the input image is 192*128, it will try to output as 192*192 instead of 192*128)), but no longer has any out-of-bounds accesses.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the flipping issue was an issue with indexing. At the start of the loop I changed it to `X = [y x]` and then on all lines after `Xsource = X + dsum / weightsum;` I swapped all the `(1)`'s and `(2)`'s.

The stretching was solved by adding a second control line (A horizontal one spanning the image like the vertical one).